# Vscode debugger ignores breakpoints in imported modules

Tags: python

I am not a programmer. I am trying to create an addon using VScode and jacqueslucke.blender-development addon. I configured the system according to directions shown here: https://polynook.com/tutorial/set-up-blender-addon-development-environment-in-windows/

My addon for blender 2.92 works but...
The debugger stops on breakpoints in _*init*.py but ignores breakpoints in imported modules.

I tried setting "justMyCode": false" in launch.json, changing python to blender and back.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

It was my fault.

The wrong module path in import function "pakage.module" instead of ".package.module" (the dot at the beginning) was the reason.

I didn't know that addon is copied into the blender scripts folder and then debugged.
My disorientation was caused by fact that the addon was fully functional with those mistakes.

I am still learning. Thanks, everyone.